# Matplotlib errorbar plot does not use marker cycling

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following example, the error bar plot does not use the marker cycle specified in the `axes` rc, although it does use the color cycle. Specifying `fmt` rather than `marker` in the `cycler` throws an `AttributeError: Unknown property fmt`. How can I use the `prop_cycle` to specify the markers of an error bar plot? I am using Matplotlib 1.5.1 and Python 3.5.1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=cycler(color=['orange', 'violet', 'darkgreen'],
                                 marker=['s', 'o', 'd']))
plt.rc('lines', linestyle=None)
plt.errorbar((0, 1), (1, 0), yerr=(0.1, 0.1))
plt.errorbar((0, 1), (0, 1), yerr=(0.1, 0.1))
plt.errorbar((0, 1), (0.5, 0.75), yerr=(0.1, 0.1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this doesn't answer the question as posed, there are two ways to get around this using a `prop_cycle`. One is to simply use a `for` loop to construct the graphs. If you'd rather not use a `for` loop, you can define a generator function to `yield` values of the markers. This has the disadvantage that it doesn't automatically reset for every axis, but I think its easier to use than a `for` loop. The `while True:` statement is necessary to get it to loop back to the beginning as though it were a cycle of markers to use.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

def mfunc(syms):
    while True:
        for s in syms:
            yield s

markers = ['s', 'o']
mark = mfunc(markers)
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=cycler(color=['orange', 'violet', 'darkgreen']))
plt.rc('lines', linestyle=None)
plt.errorbar((0, 1), (1, 0), yerr=(0.1, 0.1), marker=next(mark))
plt.errorbar((0, 1), (0, 1), yerr=(0.1, 0.1), marker=next(mark))
plt.errorbar((0, 1), (0.5, 0.75), yerr=(0.1, 0.1), marker=next(mark))
```

[image]

Comment: your `mfunc` is effectively the same as `itertools.cycle`, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe? I'm not sure, I'm not familiar with that function.